# Are parents responsible if a child leaves Islam?

Tags: parents, children, halal-haram

Salam,

Are parents responsible if a child decides to leave Islam ? If parents did teach Islam, rules, to the child during childhood.

Answer (score 1):

Salaam. A parent can only teach their children, but cannot force a child to believe in something. Islamic law prohibits forced conversion, following the Quranic principle that there is "no compulsion in religion" (Quran 2:256). Thus, the best thing you can do is pray to Allah (swt) to guide your child and also try to give resources to your child. I hope this helps:)

-Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Was prophet Nuh responsible when his son refused to enter the boat and instead ran to a high mountain for shelter and ended up perishing? Did Allah blame prophet Nuh for that?

Comment: You mean Noah ...

Comment: Ah yes, I did indeed.. Typing too fast -- will edit